# rsync flags for backing up /home/$USER/

Tags: backup, rsync, deja-dup

I am writing a basic script to backup some of the directories in $HOME. I started with the -aAV flags but wonder if I should include any more flags that are useful for backups. My current script is the following:

```
rsync -aAv --exclude={"/backup/*","/deja-dup/*","/Desktop/*","/Downloads/*","/Dropbox/*","/Music/*","/Pictures/*","/Videos"} /home/$USER/ /home/$USER/backup/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I'd recommend Crash Plan, it's free and reliable.

Comment: I use the following flags `-targovuHl`. `rsync --help` shows what they do.

Comment: I'd recommend reading `man rsync`. Your choice of options depends on what you want to do. This is different from what I want to do with `rsync`, and my `rsync` options don't apply.

Comment: @Harris I think most of the flags you mentioned (-targovuHl) are covered by the -a that you also use:
" -a, --archive                archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)"

Answer (score 1):

I see you have started already **excluding certain paths** from your backup, with `--exclude`.  One of the most useful rsync flags I have found is `-F` which simply allows you to place such lists of exclude file-patterns anywhere in your source tree.

For example, I have many directories where there are C files I want to backup but not the objects, or git directories where I don't want the .git backed up, etc.  In any directory I can place a file `.rsync-filter` which holds patterns, just like --exclude, for that directory (and all sub-directories as usual depending on your pattern).  `rsync -F` will look for these files and obey the exclusion (or inclusion) rules in them.

The filter rules are a bit hard to master, but if you stick to simple cases, and always test with a `-nv` you can trim down your backups to something small and useful.